# iPhone - how to scroll two UITableViews symmetrically

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

In my app, I have two tableViews side by side. When the user scrolls on, I would like the second one to scroll at the same time, so it looks almost like one table with two different columns. I'm a bit lost on how to go about doing this, any suggestions?

Thanks, 
Greg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to look into the `UIScrollViewDelegate` - say you've got two scroll views, **A** and **B**.

Use the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method of scroll view **A** to get the offset, and then  in the same method call `setContentOffset` on scroll view **B**, passing in the value you get from the delegate.

It actually shouldn't be more than 2-3 lines of code once you've set-up your delegate methods.

Comment: Yeah, works beautifully :) thanks! I would vote up, but I don't have 15 rep points XD

Comment: It did when I wrote this! I make no guarantees that future iOS versions break it, but I don't see why they would have.

Answer (score 11):

Conveniently, UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. There exists a UIScrollViewDelegate, which has this method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

If you implement that method, you can get the `contentOffset` property of the `scrollView` argument. Then, you should use

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and set the new content offset. So something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    UIScrollView *otherScrollView = (scrollView == self.tableView1) ? self.tableView2 : self.tableView1;
    [otherScrollView setContentOffset:[scrollView contentOffset] animated:NO];
}
```

You can cast to a UITableView if you'd like, but there's no particular reason to do so.

Comment: I'd say its semantically better to cast as a UITableView, and is good for readability. Programmatically in this case though, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 7):

also, the tableview that got scrolled by the user should not be sent setContentOffset: message in scrollViewDidScroll, since it will get the app into endless cycle. so additional UIScrollViewDelegate methods should be implemented in order to solve the problem:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    beingScrolled_ = nil;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{    
    if(beingScrolled_ == nil)
        beingScrolled_ = scrollView;
}
```

and modifying Inspire48's version scrollViewDidScroll: accordingly:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    UIScrollView *otherScrollView = (scrollView == self.tableView1) ? self.tableView2 : self.tableView1;
    if(otherScrollView != beingScrolled)
    {
        [otherScrollView setContentOffset:[scrollView contentOffset] animated:NO];
    }
}
```

where beingScrolled_ is an ivar of type UIScrollView

Answer (score 1):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. Swift solution:

```
extension yourViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let otherScrollView = (scrollView == tableViewLeft) ? tableViewRight : tableViewLeft
        otherScrollView?.setContentOffset(scrollView.contentOffset, animated: false)
    }
}
```

And stop the bounce of both the tables

```
tableViewLeft.bounces = false
tableViewRight.bounces = false
```

If you want to make vertical scroll Indicators go, write the below code

```
tableViewLeft.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
tableViewRight.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

Answer (score 0):

in swift scroll two uitableviews symmetrically:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if tb_time1 == scrollView {
        tb_time2.contentOffset = tb_time1.contentOffset
    }else if tb_time2 == scrollView {
        tb_time1.contentOffset = tb_time2.contentOffset
    }
}
```

Comment: Wondering if you can help me here.  I have a collectionview inside a tableview and want to sync the scrolling.  How would I do this? Do i have to sent the tableviews delegate to the collectionviews cell somehow so they both rely on the same `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`?