# How to scroll two table views at same time but on different time interval in iphone?

Tags: iphone

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.035 target:self selector:@selector(scrollTableView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.065 target:self selector:@selector(scrollTableView1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) scrollTableView 
{    
    float w = 1;
    CGPoint scrollPoint = leftTable.contentOffset;
    scrollPoint.y = scrollPoint.y + w;
    if (scrollPoint.y >= leftTable.contentSize.height - (leftTable.frame.size.height - 100)  || scrollPoint.x <= -leftTable.frame.size.height + 924) {
        w *= -1;
    }
    [leftTable setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated: NO];
}

-(void) scrollTableView1 
{
    float w = 1;
    CGPoint scrollPoint = rightTable.contentOffset;
    scrollPoint.y = scrollPoint.y + w;
    if (scrollPoint.y >= rightTable.contentSize.height - (rightTable.frame.size.height - 100)  || scrollPoint.x <= -rightTable.frame.size.height + 924) {
        w *= -1;
    }
    [rightTable setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated: NO];
}
```

I am using this code it is working nice and both table views scroll on different time duration as I want but when I drag any of one table view while another table view is stop scrolling.I want if I drag one table view another one should be scrolled on its scheduled time interval.

Comment: Duplicate :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949142/iphone-how-to-scroll-two-uitableviews-symmetrically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334340/scrolling-two-uitableviews-together

Comment: @Rushabh:Thanks for your reply..I tried both by using this my both table view scrolling at the same time.I want if I drag one table view another one should be scrolled on its given scheduled time interval.