# Swift - scrollView.scrollEnabled = true then requires a new drag?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a smaller child scrollview inside a parent scrollview. I want the child to have scrolling disabled, so that when the user drags on the screen only the parent scrollview scrolls, then once the parent reaches a certain content offset to enable scrolling on the child scrollview, *with the same drag*.

Currently, the child scroll is disabled, then the parent scrollview reaches the desired offset and enables scrolling on the child, but you need to take your finger off the screen and initiate a new drag to be able to scroll the now-enabled child scrollview.

Why is this? Is there any way to enable the scrollview and start scrolling it with the same drag?

Edit:

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll (scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == outerScroll {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y == 10 {
            outerscroll.scrollEnabled = false
            innerScroll.scrollEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949142/iphone-how-to-scroll-two-uitableviews-symmetrically

Comment: @Vemonus how is that relevant to this problem? That person was attempting to scroll two scrollviews at the same time.

Comment: Post some code please, show where exactly you are setting the `scrollEnabled` property.

Comment: @danmartin The second paragraph made it seem like you wanted to scroll two scrollviews with the same scroll; is that inaccurate?

Comment: @Vemonus Apologies, perhaps my explanation wasn't clear. I have a scrollview inside a bigger scrollview. When the user starts dragging, i want only the parent scrollview to scroll, but after a certain point, I want the parent scrollview to stop scrolling and the child scrollview to start scrolling, within the same drag. Currently after I enable scrolling in the child scrollview, I then need to lift my thumb off and begin a new drag to carry on scrolling in the child scrollview.

Comment: @impression7vx Sorry - added some code now.

Comment: Are innerScroll and outerScroll class variables? This seems right, but just want to make sure! Also, are you able to scroll the outerScrollView WITHOUT taking your finger off the screen AFTER you reach contentOffset.y?

Comment: @danmartin Hi Dan did you end up finding a solution?